# Menor valor (Variáveis DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax

Preciso criar uma medida (MAX) que calcule o menor entre várias variáveis, igualmente a que temos no Excel chamada "MENOR"...

Minha tentativa está na seguinte forma ("Sem sucesso")

```
M_Teste =
var v1 = 10
var v2 = 8 
var v3 = 11
var v4 = 9
return min(v1,v2,v3,v4)
```

Tentei criar uma DATATABLE para criar uma tabela virtual para utilizar a MINX, mas não consegui!

Answer (score 1):

Seria possível através do MINX.

```
M_Teste = 
   var v1 = 10
   var v2 = 8 
   var v3 = 11
   var v4 = 9
return 
   MINX({v1,v2,v3,v4},[Value])
```